# setup-database-server-with-postgresql-and-pgadmin3

Tags: postgresql

We have set up postgres 9.0 on our new debian 6.0 server

We want to remotely connect to this database server.

We followed the steps in the below url
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-setup-database-server-with-postgresql-and-pgadmin3.html

But when restart our database it thows the foloowing error

**authentication option not in name=value format: sameuser**

Any advice on how to access database server remotely using pgadmin 3 would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

According to [this link](http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Can-t-start-postmaster-on-HEAD-td1994847.html), there was changed format of configuration file `pg_hba.conf`. Remove, please, keyword `sameuser` from it.